# What are alternatives to block?

Tags: beamer, color, environments

I use `\begin{block} ... \end{block}` to describe formalization of some notions, and I want to write some examples under it. I still would like to stick to the structure of a block (one part for title and the other part for the content), but it is desirable to use another color to distinguish the example from the notion.

Could anyone tell me what I could use to embed the example?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

How about using the `alertblock` or the `exampleblock` environment?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usecolortheme{whale}
\usecolortheme{orchid}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{A frame}

\begin{block}{A block environment}
Some text.
\end{block}

\begin{alertblock}{An alertblock environment}
Some text.
\end{alertblock}

\begin{exampleblock}{An exampleblock environment}
Some text.
\end{exampleblock}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 22):

It's probably a bit late to join the party. However...

...the [tcolorbox](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) package provides some beautiful and flexible block environments (PGF-based) that specifically support "split boxes" with an upper and a lower half. As of version 1.1 (2012-03-01), there is also a complete English documentation available (previous versions where German only).

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{A frame}

\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=blue!5,colframe=blue!75!black,title=My title]
  My cool formalization
  \tcblower
  $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{i=1}^n i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I followed your link to ctan and discovered English documentation, too.  Thank you, this package looks quite nice!

Comment: @mbork: Thanks, just found it. The English documentation is brand new (from 1st of March), so it seems that you looked at it right in time. I have edited this into the answer.

Comment: @Daniel, do you know how to add the following code to a beamer theme file, beamerthemeEx1sty, to override the default theme style to have a particular type of block framed?

Comment: @Vass: Please ask that as a new question (including a MWE).