# how to change the style of the block environment in beamer?

Tags: beamer, beamerposter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are alternatives to block?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27093/what-are-alternatives-to-block)

I am using Beamer to write a poster. I wish to have various kind of blocks to contain different contents, like theorem, example, references, etc. But the following codes

```
\begin{block}{aha}    
...
\end{block}
```

always give the same appearance. Does anyone know how to change the appearance?

I am also using theorem environment, it looks exactly like a block.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27093/what-are-alternatives-to-block

Comment: Does the question @lockstep linked to help you? If yes, we can close this question as a duplicate.