# Container with border radius

Tags: color

I have a para that is wrapped in a container. The container has a container heading , border radius on the corners and color. How do I achieve it with LaTex? I have attached a sample sketch for reference. The shaded portion will be filled with color

[image]

Comment: Look at the `tcolorbox` package. Search the site for multiple examples, or look at the manual.

Comment: One example: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27093/what-are-alternatives-to-block/46420#46420

Comment: Another example: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/173039/586 Note the `arc` keyword, for setting the roundness of the corners.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is literally the default setting of `tcolorbox`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[title={Heading}]
  Some Text \ldots
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]